# lambda implemented properties both getter and setter?

Tags: c#, lambda

Let's say we have the following code:

```
class Person
{
   public string firstname = "Unknown";
   public string Name => firstname = "John";
}     
Person p = new Person();
Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
```

so the output is

> "John"

I'm a little bit confused , and have some questions:

Q1-is Name property acts as a setter and getter?

Q2-I didn't ask it return anything, I though lambda expression can only return sth without "=" in it, for example

p => p.name

there is no "=" in it, so p.name is return
if there is "=" as p => p.name = "john", isn't that it just modify the name and return nothing?

Comment: Q1: No. A property defined like this is automatically readonly. _But_ you actually assign a new value to another field while getting the value ... very special case.

Comment: This is no lambda expression or "lambda implemented property", but an [expression-bodied property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members).

Comment: Your lambda is a getter with a side-effect of setting the value of `firstname`. The equivalent getter would be written as `return firstname = "John";` which first sets `firstname` and then returns the value of `firstname`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lambda is nothing but a delegate. A delegate is any arbitrary method, with or without parameters as well as with our without return-type. So your action may or may not return something.

In your case `firstName = John` **will** return something, the result of the assignment, which is the assigned value. In your case this will return `"John"`.

Your code is equivalent to the following, which my illustrate that better:

```
class Person
{
    public string firstname = "Unknown";
    public string Name { get { return firstname = "John"; } }
}
```

To have a property get and set-able, you´d need two lambdas - actually two **methods** - namely a get- and a set-method:

```
public string Name
{
    get => /* any code that expects nothing and returns a string */
    set => /* any code that expects a string and does not return anything */
}
```

You have only one - the get-method - which makes your property get-only. However you have a side-effect in that method which modifies another member - `firstname` which may lead to high confusion and thus should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Property Name in this case is read-only. Assignment operator has return value equal to what was assigned. If you write something like:

```
Console.WriteLine(somevariable = "Test");
```

You will get "Test" in console, because the result of assignment operator is equal to the value assigned.

In other words - your property is read-only, but on each call it will write "John" to firstname and return its value. Not a great pattern for a getter.